# Can the Shield spell be used with shield master feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats

Would casting the shield spell allow you to get bonus saving throw to spells targeting you or to an effect that would damage you?

Answer (score 12):

While the name of the spell is *shield*, it does not create one, but

> An invisible barrier of magical force (PHB 275)

The description is always the place where you can find how the spell fits in the rules, mechanical effects are always mentioned there, directly or indirectly. Interacting with other features is a mechanical effect.

Comment: Another evidence that the *shield spell* does not a shield make, a character wielding a shield still gains full benefits from the shield spell, yet [characters cannot wield two shields](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/08/14/wielding-two-shields/).Even though it is not a crawford tweet.

Answer (score 4):

*Shield* specifically adds to your Armor Class and not your Saving Throw bonuses:

> **Shield**
>   Until the start of your next turn, you have a +5 bonus **to AC**

Spells do what they say they do on the tin, no more no less, and that means, though a bit weird, *Shield* will only protect you from **attacks**. If it is a harmful effect that requires a **Save** (like a Fireball or Disintigrate), Shield is no use.

Answer (score 2):

The *Shield* spell, despite being a barrier, is not an actual "shield" in terms of what the game mechanics recognize as such, so no. *Shield Master* also is specific with its wording:

> You gain the following benefits while you are wielding a shield:

The use of the words "wielding" and "a" indicate quite specifically that it must be a shield armament and cannot include the *Shield* spell.